# Adding a new object to an ArrayList that is an attribute of another class

Tags: java, class, oop, object, arraylist

I am getting an error when trying to add a new object to an ArrayList that is an attribute of another class. Let me explain.

**UML**

I do have 2 classes in my model:

1. Equipo
2. Jugador

To simplify things let's call Equipo -> Team & Jugador -> Player.

For each Team there will be multiple players, so I have created an ArrayList of type Player as an attribute in the Team class.

1. Equipo

   ```
   public class Equipo {
       private String nombre;
       private LocalDate fechaAlta;
       private String continente;
       private char clasificado;

       private ArrayList <Jugador> listaJugadores; //Muestra la relación 

       public Equipo(String nombre, LocalDate fechaAlta, String continente, char clasificado) {
           this.nombre = nombre;
           this.fechaAlta = fechaAlta;
           this.continente = continente;
           this.clasificado = clasificado;
       }
       .
       .
       .
   }
   ```
2. Jugador

   ```
   public class Jugador {
       private String jugador;
       private int dorsal;

       public Jugador(String jugador, int dorsal) {
           this.jugador = jugador;
           this.dorsal = dorsal;
       }
       .
       .
       .
   }
   ```

**MAIN**

In the main class I have created and initialized the Teams and Players ArrayLists.

```
public static Ventana v1;
public static ArrayList <Equipo> listaEquipos;
public static ArrayList <Jugador> listaJugadores;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    v1 = new Ventana();
    v1.getearComboBox();
    v1.setVisible(true);

    //Inicializar arrays
    listaEquipos = new ArrayList <Equipo>();
    listaJugadores = new ArrayList <Jugador>();
```

I am trying to add a Player to the last Team in the Array

```
public static void inscribirJugador(String nombreJugador, String dorsalString){
        //Conversion del dorsal
        int dorsal = Integer.parseInt(dorsalString);

        listaEquipos.get(listaEquipos.size()-1).getListaJugadores().add(new Jugador("nombreJugador", dorsal));    
}
```

However I am getting this NullPointerException error that I am not being able to solve.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqfgW.jpg

LINE 98: `listaEquipos.get(listaEquipos.size()-1).getListaJugadores().add(new Jugador("nombreJugador", dorsal));`

Comment: In class `Equipo`, where do you call `this.listaJugadores = new ArrayList<>()`? I see you declare a private variable, but you do not initialize it, so it is null.

Comment: Sure I forgot about that! I have added below the error picture where the error is pointing to.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas ohhh you are completely right. Thank you very much, I am quite new to OOP and programming in general but Im trying my best to improve.

Comment: Learn to use the [debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) in your [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment), to examine the value of things. You would have seen that at runtime `listaJugadores` was `null` rather than the empty `ArrayList` you expected.

Answer (score 1):

If you did not put at least a team in the ArrayList, you are calling `getListaJugadores` on a null object.
In fact, if the ArrayList `listaEquipos` is empty, you will return null on the method invocation `listaEquipos.get(listaEquipos.size() -1)`. You got to have at least one team to retrieve the list of players!